# How to write into an existing Excel-Worksheet to the first empty row with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

my question is, how I can write data to an existing Excel-Worksheet using Python.
I've tried a few ways so far, but nothing worked out, yet. For example it would be enough to have like 3 columns were I want add data to the 1st and the 3rd column in that specific empty row.
That's one try to simply write to an existing file so far:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook("example.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

ws["A4"] = 5
```

Comment: What are few ways you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried xlrd, xlwt or openpyxl, but I wasn't able to write to an existing sheet right now

Comment: Can you show the `nothing` (code) that did not worked out

Comment: Share us the code you tried so far.

Comment: `ws.append()` will automatically write to the next row in a worksheet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ws.max_row` would give you the last used row number. You can use this as follows to add a new value:

```
import openpyxl    

filename = 'example.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.active
ws.cell(column=1, row=ws.max_row+1, value=5)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: Now when I want to use it for my real Excel-File, I get the UserWarnings: "Conditional Formatting extension is not supported and will be removed" and "Data Validation extension is not supported  and will be removed", which completely messes up my file. Do you know any workarounds for this aswell?

Comment: The only thing which fully supports an Excel file is Excel itself. If you are using Windows you can use Python to tell Excel to manipulate your file. Search for scripts containing: `win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')`